# Run the second condition if first query result not found in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Keeping in mind that the first query needs to run first, and the second should only be activated if the first one returns an empty result.

```
db.collection.findOne({a:'xyz',b:'xy',c:'x'});
db.collection.findOne({a:'xyz',b:'xy',c:null});
```

and one more here I have written two separate queries so I want to satisfy the above in one single query.

I had tried with $and $or but it is not working properly. example:-

```
db.collection.findOne({$or:[{a:'xyz',b:'xy',c:'x'},{a:'xyz',b:'xy',c:null}]});
```

but here if both the entries present in DB then every time second is executing.

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order of your queries? If you always get second then make the second your first and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
db.collection.find({a:'xyz', b:'xy', c: { $in: ["x", null] } }).sort({c: -1}).limit(1);
```

The above query finds all documents for which `c` is either `"x"` *or* is null.  It then sorts descending on `c`, which would place the null results to the end.  By limiting to 1 document using `limit(1)`, it means we would get back an `c: "x"` document, if it exists, otherwise, we would get back a null document.